# How to have a scrollbar in my div not in my window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hello everybody**, I have a window (I use electronJS) with a div where I add elements with Javascript with the function -- > document.createElement('section').

There is the Javascript loop for add elements:

```
for (var i = 0; i < (clippy_array.length); i++) {
    counter_test += 1;
    console.log("TCL: counter", counter_test);
    var element = document.createElement('section');
    var addHere = document.getElementById('Content');
    addHere.appendChild(element);
    element.textContent = clippy_array[i];
    element.className = "TextCP";
    element.id = "Element" + i;
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#f5f5f5";
    element.style.display = "block";
    element.style.marginTop = "5px";
    element.style.marginBottom = "5px";
    element.style.border = "2px solid black";
    element.style.minHeight = "90px";
    element.style.padding = "5px";
}
```

---

**My problem:** The list of elements added is very long then there is a scroll bar in my window but I don't want a scrollbar in my window but in my div, how I can do that (and if it is possible, i would like to have a personalized scrollbar), I put a screenshot to help you to understand.

[First screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3iOA.png)
[Second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWVTq.png)
**Thanks for your help !!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `height` of the `div` to a static value and then set the [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) on the `div` to `scroll` if you always want a scrollbar or `auto` if you only want the scrollbar when there is overflowed content. You can also use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` to specify which scrollbars to produce. Here's an example:

```css
div { width: 200px; height:200px; overflow:scroll; }
```

```html
<div>
;kdsjf ;lsadjf sd;lfkj sdf;lksdj f;sldkfj sa;flksjd f;lsadkfj sd;lfksjd f;lsdkfj sal;fkjs dfl;ksdjf s;adlkfjs adf;lksdajf s;adlkfj asdf;lkasjd f;lksadfj sd;lkfj sdf;lksdjf ;lsdkfj sad;lfkjsd fl;sdjf sdlkfj sdlfkjdsa flskdajf sdl;kfj sdf;lksdj fl;sdkfj asd;lfkjsad f;laskdjf as;dlfkj sad;lfksajd f;lsakdjf sad;lkfjsd ;lfksadjf ;lasdkfj sda;lkfjs dafl;ksadj f;lsadkfj sda;lkfjsd fl;ksdajf l;sakdfj s;dlakfjs daflksdj
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use `overflow: auto` if you only want the scroll bar to appear _when the content overflows_.

Comment: Thanks that's work but why there is a space between my title bar and my div when I use the element inspector there is no object !? Thanks :)

Comment: @DinoGrrr Probably because of margins. We can't say for sure unless you post your HTML. But, that is an unrelated question to what you are asking about.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Oh yes ! Sure ! I ask that here because open a subject take a bit time :D